# Counting data with same id in R

Tags: r, count

I am trying to find count how much time the same movid is played.

[image: This is data I am using]

Thanks to comments,

This is frequency of movie played

```
  > c<-head(table(B$movid),n=5)
  > head(as.data.frame(c),n=5)
      id Freq
  1    1  452
  2    2  131
  3    3   90
  4    4  209
  5    5   86
```

*1. For this data, I would like to know how to +1 to frequency value for each id*

This is rating data

```
  > d<-table(B$movid[B$rating>4])
  > head(as.data.frame(d),n=5)
      id Freq 
  1    1  119
  2    2    9
  3    3   11
  4    4   29
  5    5    6
```

*2. After I find this proportion(d/c) as a vector matrix to create new matrix.*

Thank you for your time and thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe as there are multiple questions in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Kim Please use `dput` to show the data instead of image as it is not possible to copy data from image.

Comment: @akrun, May I ask another comments for what I updated? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `table` to find the frequency

```
table(df1$movid)
```

For the second question

```
length(unique(df1$movid[df1$rating>3.5]))
```